# How to toggle images using file paths in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the image shown when a button is clicked.

```js
function change() {
  if (document.getElementById("toggle").src == "/folder/original.jpg") {
    document.getElementById("toggle").src = "/folder/new.jpg";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("toggle").src = "/folder/original.jpg";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="change()">Click</button>
<img id="toggle" src="/folder/original.jpg">
```

I've tried it with a url to check if my code works and it does. When using file paths, the image shown is `/folder/original.jpg` but doesn't change. I've inspected the element and there are no errors when I click on `button`. I've also tested to see if `/folder/new.jpg` would render and it does. Why doesn't it work when I use file paths?

Comment: What do you mean when you say `file paths`? Do you mean images served over `file:///`?

Comment: @RobbieJW the folder that the image is in in your computer.

Comment: `console.log(document.getElementById("toggle").src)` and check it's value

Comment: @TJ ```http://127.0.0.1:5000/folder/original.jpg/``` then ```undefined```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking the src property of the image which will be the full path of the image, to use check the exact path you set the attribute you have to check against the image attribute.

```
function change() {
  if (document.getElementById("toggle").getAttribute('src') == "/folder/original.jpg")
  {
    document.getElementById("toggle").setAttribute('src', "/folder/new.jpg");
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById("toggle").setAttribute('src', "/folder/original.jpg");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** You can check if the `src` value ends with the path.

```js
function change() {
  const img = document.getElementById("toggle");
  if (img.src.replace(/\\/g, '/').endsWith('/folder/original.jpg')) {
    img.src = "/folder/new.jpg";
  } else {
    img.src = "/folder/original.jpg";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="change()">Click</button>
<img id="toggle" src="./folder/original.jpg">
```

If the actual src is the path on the file system, then it will look like this in WIndows:

> `file:///C:\folder\original.jpg`

You can check if it matches using:

```js
const src = 'file:///C:\\folder\\original.jpg';
const isEqual = src.replace(/\\/g, '/').endsWith('/folder/original.jpg');

console.log(isEqual); // true
```

---

Here is an example using absolute paths:

```js
const images = [
  'http://placekitten.com/240/120',
  'http://placekitten.com/200/120'
];

function change() {
  const img = document.getElementById('toggle');
  let index = images.indexOf(img.src);
  if (index === -1) index = images.length - 1;
  const nextIndex = (images.length + index + 1) % images.length;
 
  img.src = images[nextIndex];
}
```

```css
body > button { display: block; }
```

```html
<button onclick="change()">Click</button>
<img id="toggle" src="http://placekitten.com/240/120">
```

Comment: *"When using file paths, the image shown is /folder/original.jpg"* - apparently the file paths work

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with some regex to get the file name

```js
function change() {
  var imgSrc = document.getElementById("toggle").src;
  var filename = imgSrc.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
  
  if (filename == "original.jpg")
  {
    document.getElementById("toggle").src = "/folder/new.jpg";
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById("toggle").src = "/folder/original.jpg";
  }
  
  console.log(filename);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="change()">Click</button>
<img id="toggle" src="/folder/original.jpg">
```